# How do I toggle a CSS class based on a boolean, with Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to add or remove a CSS class from an element, based on a boolean. I want a nicer version of this:

```
if (condition) {
  element.classes.add('important');
} else {
  element.classes.remove('important');
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dart's HTML library has two ways to [toggle](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/CssClassSet.html#toggle) CSS classes on an element. (Well, four ways if you count [toggleAll](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/CssClassSet.html#toggleAll) :)

To add a class if it's missing, or remove a class if it already exists, use `toggle(String className)`:

```
element.classes.toggle('important');
```

To toggle a CSS class based on a boolean value, use `toggle(String className, [bool shouldAdd])`:

```
element.classes.toggle('important', condition);
```

Here's the original feature request, which links to the commit that adds this feature: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11741

Comment: the optional parameter name is a bit confusing shouldn't it be `[bool shouldToggle]` currently it seems like it only effects the adding of the class (unless that is the case), just a thought.